# How to calculate numbers of Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

How to calculate numbers of threads , if i create two new Threads in method run ? Its creates many times , and fall when memory is over .

```
public class RabbitLab {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
    }

}


class RabbitPrinter implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
      for ( int y=0 ; y < 3 ; y++){
        System.out.println("New rabbit born!");
        int x=0;
        while (x != 3) {
      {

        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
      x++

    }

        }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are counting in the wrong direction, causing an infinite loop:

```
    int x=0;
    while (x != 3) {
        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
        x--;
    }
```

Try instead:

```
    int x=3;
    while (x != 0) {
        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
        x--;
    }
```

Or:

```
    int x=0;
    while (x != 3) {
        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
        x++;
    }
```

Either of the latter two versions will run three times, each time starting two new threads, creating a total of six threads.

To get exactly `n` threads, use a simple `for` loop:

```
const int n = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
}
```

Or, as a `while` loop:

```
    int x = 3;
    while (x != 0) {
        new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
        x--;
    }
```

Comment: oh... its doesn't matters , When I start new Thread , its NEW x = 0 , And all Threads start from x = 0 , and start increment it to 3 ,but i want to get the nubmer of threads for example 8; And in RabbitPrinter i run two new Threads . 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8  , and in this moment i want to STOP ; How do it ?

Comment: Just spawn *ONE thread* per iteration? Or count the exact number of threads, i.e. `x += 2`, instead of `x++`.

Comment: Note that you cannot spawn an odd number of threads if you spawn two at every iteration.

Comment: Use my `for` loop with `n = 8`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do .

here `x = 0` and you are matching `x!=3` and decrementing `x`.. so `x` will never be 3.

increment the x instead of decrementing....

```
x++
```

Comment: oh... its doesn't matters , When I start new Thread , its NEW x = 0 , And all Threads start from x = 0 , and start increment it to 3 ,

Comment: but you are decementing .. increment the x.. see my edited answer

Comment: its small mistake , im sorry , but my question is still up

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want your loop counter to apply to all of the threads, not just one, so instead of using 'x' as a local variable, you should declare it as static (so it is shared by all instances) and an AtomicInteger (so all threads can update it safely without contention issues):

Try this:

```
class RabbitPrinter implements Runnable {
private static AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(0);
 public void run() {
  for ( int y=0 ; y < 3 ; y++){
    System.out.println("New rabbit born!");

    while (x.getAndIncrement() < 3) {
     new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
     new Thread(new RabbitPrinter()).start();
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a certain number of threads and stop when you reach your limit by using FixedThreadPool from (Executors) [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29]

Apart from that the ExecutorService provides utility methods to shutdown your pool.